# Repeat vs Repetition - are they exactly the same?

Tags: synonyms, proverbs

Can the proverb "Repetition is the mother of studies" be replaced by "Repeat is the mother of studies"? Repeat can also be used as a noun, and according to many dictionaries, both repeat and repetition mean "the act of repeating".

My gut feeling is that repetition is more natural English. Any comments?

Comment: _Repeat_ is the verb (_Don't repeat yourself_), and _repetition_ is the noun formed from it. In the sentence you give, _Repetition_ is the subject, and therefore must be a noun; you can't use a bare infinitive verb root instead.

Comment: The [noun _repeat_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155388/repeat-vs-repetition-are-they-exactly-the-same) is used as well, but not in the same sense as _repetition_. For instance, when a television series is broadcast, and it is not the first time a specific episode was broadcast, that episode is a _repeat_.

Comment: Whether or not *repeat* can be a noun is a red herring. Proverbs are fixed phrases. You can't just go around replacing words in them. And why would you do that in the first place? "Orange goat is the mother of studies" is impeccable English. It's just not a proverb anymore.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot make that edit without changing the meaning of the proverb.

To *repeat* is to do something one additional time.

*Repetition* is the practice of doing something multiple times, often sufficiently more than once.

Since the proverb means:

> [Doing something multiple times] is the mother of studies.

changing "Repetition" to "repeat" would likewise alter its meaning to:

> [Doing something one additional time] is the mother of studies.

, which is a subtly different thing.  (You don't learn as much by only practicing your song twice than if you do it a dozen times.)

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not.

I cannot think of a context in which I would understand *repeat* as a noun meaning *the act of repeating*. I am familiar with the noun *repeat* meaning *an instance of something which has previously occurred* (nearly always in the context of television programmes).